# Linux Message Queue for OpenCV C++

Tags: linux, opencv, message-queue

I have a thread that gets new frames, 2 other threads that process the newly gotten image and 1 that prints the output based on the processing threads.

The program cycle goes,

```
>thread 3, print an output based on the previous outputs of the thread 0 and 1
>thread 0 get new image
>> thread 1, process image for color
>> thread 2, process image for haar cascade
```

going cyclically 3&0>1&2>3&0>1&2>

'>' indicates join before spawning the next set

How do I pass the opencv Mat between the threads 0 to 1&2?

Also how would I pass the data from threads 1&2 to thread 0?

I would guess a message queue system, how does one implement that?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect I may get some abuse and down-votes for this because global variables are generally frowned upon, however I feel the situation is different in image-processing where:

- the code is multi-threaded, and
- the data structures (images) are large.

Here I think it is important to avoid expensive copying and *"transmission"* of data down sockets etc. when it is already available in memory that is shared and visible amongst threads.

So, in concrete terms, I would go for an array, or vector (according to your preference) of say 16 OpenCV Mats that is **globally** accessible.

Acquire into the first, notify the the next thread when that buffer is full, then acquire into the next. And so on.

As regards the notification, you have several options. The cleanest, and most modern is probably using condition variables letting each processing thread (not the acquiring thread) wait on a condvar for *"buffer full"*. Next is probably POSIX message queues, though if you are porting to macOS later you may regret that as there is no support. Another, easily programmed method is to use sockets but just send a single byte that is the index into the global array of 16 Mats - that way there is no problem with incomplete, multi-byte reads on sockets. The processing threads then just sit in a loop doing blocking reads on the socket to know which buffer to process. You can also define a special index that means *"quit"*.

---

Check the size of your images in terms of width x height x channels x bytes per channel and get a feel for how much memory a global vector of 16 Mats will need and be sure you have that available before using this strategy - you may be up against the wall with a Raspberry Pi for example.